# Spring FeignClient: NumberFormatException when parsing service port

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, ribbon, spring-cloud-feign

I am using Netflix Eureka + Netlifx Zuul and am trying to use Feign client to send a request from one microservice to another. I am able to access all microservices through zuul, however, when I try to make request from one microservice to another, I get an error.

I've managed to figure out, it has something to do, with port parsing. It throws NumberFormatException, because it can't parse "8084:80" when making url. If the port was simply 8084, it would've worked fine, cause 8084 is the port of the service I'm trying to send the request to.

```
feign.RetryableException: Error at index 4 in: "8084:80" executing POST http://prediction/task
    at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:249) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:129) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.runTask(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at lj.uni.fri.scheduler.service.SchedulerService.setCurrentTime(SchedulerService.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Error at index 4 in: "8084:80"
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:706) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at feign.Client$Default.convertAndSend(Client.java:148) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:103) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:93) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.3.BUILD-20200514.112700-81.jar:2.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.3.BUILD-20200514.112700-81.jar:2.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:104) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.3.BUILD-20200514.112700-81.jar:2.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Error at index 4 in: "8084:80"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forCharSequence(NumberFormatException.java:84) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(URLStreamHandler.java:232) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:701) ~[na:na]
    ... 57 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code -1
```

This is the feign client I use:

```java
package lj.uni.fri.scheduler.feign;

import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@FeignClient(name = "prediction")
public interface PredictionServiceFeign {

    @PostMapping("/task")
    String runTask(@RequestBody LocalDateTime dateTime);

}
```

This is the config of the service running on port 8084:

bootstrap.yml

```yaml
server:
  port: ${PORT:8084}

spring:
  application:
    name: prediction

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URL:http://localhost:8761}/eureka/
```

application.yml

```yaml
eureka:
  instance:
    non-secure-port: 80
    hostname: ${DOMAIN_NAME:localhost:${server.port}}
  password: ${EUREKA_USER_PASSWORD:password}

security:
  user:
    password: ${eureka.password}

prediction:
  http:
    auth-token-header-name: api-key
    auth-token: ${MICROSERVICE_API_KEY:verysafetoken}
```

I've tried removing the "non-secure-port" but then it threw error for "8084:8084"

As seen in the debugger, the url is correct with the exception of port:

[image]

I am using:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

PS: The same error happens if I try to use RestTemplate with @LoadBalanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I made a mistake in the config file. I had to change:

```yaml
eureka:
  instance:
    non-secure-port: 80
    hostname: ${DOMAIN_NAME:localhost:${server.port}}
```

To:

```yaml
eureka:
  instance:
    non-secure-port: 80
    hostname: ${DOMAIN_NAME:localhost}
```